# How to have border with rounded corners as an image and inner background colour to see through?

Tags: html, css

I have div border with inner rounded corners that I want to replace with an image. The image will have opacity, gradient and other Photoshop effects applied to it.

I also want to have the inner div's background colour to see through so that the image of the body is visible. Basically I am after a transparent background in the .inner div.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EN2XZ/2/

This is my HTML:

```
<body>
  <div class="outer">
     <div class="inner">
     ....
     ....
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  background-image:url('image-url');
  background-size:cover;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  padding:50px;
}
.outer {
  background-color:#000;
  padding:10px;
}
.inner {
  border-radius:10px;
  background-color:#fff;
  padding:5px 15px;
  color:#0000ff;
}
```

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/understanding-border-image/

Comment: I think the best way to do this is with border-images. http://css-tricks.com/body-border-rounded-inside/. That way you can have a single element with inner rounded corners and a transparent background.

Comment: Can we see an image of what you're going for here? Its not entirely clear.

Answer (score 1):

Am not clear about the image requirement description you gave

To get a transparent background give background color in `rgba`
Rewrite the inner  `class` as

```
.inner {
 border-radius:10px;
 background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 padding:5px 15px;
 color:#0000ff;
```

}

where the `rgba` last parameter is the `opacity`

Answer (score 0):

Currently, `.inner` can not be transparent to `body` because `.outer` is the next layer behind it, and is solid black, so `.inner` would be transparent to black.

You could remove `.outer` or set `background-color: transparent;` on it, then set `.inner` to `background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .7);`

However that leaves no border. You could add a simple black border with rounded edge by adding it to the `.inner` class: `border: 1px solid #000;`

---

If you are set on having the outer black box have no radius, and inner have a radius, and have fancy effects, then you can certainly just use an image as you originally intended.

In Photoshop, make sure your image has some transparency, and save it as a PNG-24 with transparency enabled. The PNG-24 format allows for each pixel to carry over its alpha value.